# How to get number of fetched rows after result set has been consumed?

Tags: cassandra, pagination

I followed the instruction on [the official cassandra website](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries) in order to consume the result sets of my queries in an asynchronous manner.

```
ResultSetFuture future = session.executeAsync("SELECT release_version FROM system.local");
Futures.addCallback(future,
    new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {
        @Override public void onSuccess(ResultSet result) {
            gui.setMessage("Cassandra version is " + result.one().getString("release_version"));
        }

        @Override public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            gui.setMessage("Error while reading Cassandra version: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    },
    MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()
);
```

This basically works fine but in order to see how many rows have been fetched, I wrapped my FutureCallback into a LogAwareCallback which, a bit simplified, looks like this:

```
private static final class LogAwareCallback implements FutureCallback<ResultSet> {

    private final FutureCallback<ResultSet> origin;
    private final String query;
    private final Object [] parameters;

    private LogAwareCallback(
            FutureCallback<ResultSet> origin,
            String query,
            Object [] parameters) {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.query = query;
        this.parameters = parameters;   
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ResultSet rows) {
        origin.onSuccess(rows);

        // as all rows should have been processed at this state,
        // it should be safe to call all with size now
        int resultSize = rows.all().size();
        log(query, parameters, resultSize);             
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        // FAILURE HANDLING...
    }

    private void log(String query, Object [] parameters, int resultSize) {
        // LOG result size for given query
    }
}
```

The problem though is, that the wrapped FutureCallback already consumed the whole result set at this point in time and I always get a result size of 0 although multiple rows have been processed.

Thus my question is, if there is a way to get the count of returned rows from the ResultSet even if has been fully consumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all() returns remaining rows and empties out List. So you won't be able to get number of rows processed easily. But there is an alternative,

If you changed your onSuccess in LogAwareCallback to,

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(ResultSet rows) {
        *int resultSize = rows.getAvailableWithoutFetching();*
        log(query, parameters, resultSize); 
        origin.onSuccess(rows);                    
    }
```

you will get number of rows in result set without fetching additional rows from database. This has a caveat where if number of rows total expected as result of query is greater than page size, you will only get that (page size) as output.

Comment: I tried this as well, but it gave me 0 resultSize as well.

Comment: you tried it before calling origin.onSuccess(rows); and it still gave you 0? And then it also printed '"Cassandra version is " ... ?

Comment: aaah, I see. Sorry, did not realise that you change the order of the statements. I assume getAvailableWithoutFetching is a rather lightweight operation?

Comment: yes, I would think so as it is also used lots of time in early fetch during pagination. But as I don't know internal driver code, you might want to benchmark before using in production code.

Comment: call is O(1). Pretty performant. Did this solve your problem? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you can hardly beat that (O(1)) ;-) Your answer gives me at least the right logging when no paging is involved, thus I'll accept it as there is currently no other way.